# RecyclerView with 2 column and auto resized images

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView with two column, I want to show images with different height.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#f7f5f5"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and in load images.

```
  RecyclerView recycler_item =  main.findViewById(R.id.recycler_item);
  recycler_item.setHasFixedSize(false);
  recycler_item .setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 2));
  recycler_item .setAdapter(itemAdapter);
  LayoutAnimationController animation = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(context, R.anim.layout_animation);
  recycler_item.setLayoutAnimation(animation);
  itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  recycler_item.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
```

result is

[image]

but i want to show like this

[image]

Comment: use staggered grid layout manager

Comment: Use instead the StaggeredGridLayoutManager: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Comment: How to fix image size with column width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, set `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` attribute for the `ImageView` to adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.

Now, it's time to use an instance of [`StaggeredGridLayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager) as the layout manager of the `RecyclerView` to achieve the result.

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recycler_item.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```